VFS is already closed (Disposed) in IntelliJ IDEA
Following are my IntelliJ IDEA build details
IntelliJ IDEA 2024.2.3 (Community Edition)
Build #IC-242.23339.11, built on September 25, 2024
Runtime version: 21.0.4+13-b509.17 amd64 (JCEF 122.1.9)
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
Toolkit: sun.awt.windows.WToolkit
Windows 11.0
GC: G1 Young Generation, G1 Concurrent GC, G1 Old Generation
Memory: 4018M
Cores: 8
Registry:
  ide.experimental.ui=true
  i18n.locale=
Non-Bundled Plugins:
  com.codeium.enterpriseUpdater (1.0.12)
  PythonCore (242.23339.11)
  Docker (242.23339.19)
  ch.newinstance.plugin.mavendependencychecker (1.14.0)
  org.sonarlint.idea (10.11.0.79648)
  MavenRunHelper (4.28.0-IJ2022.2)
  com.codeium.enterprise (1.16.0)
Kotlin: 242.23339.11-IJ

Intermittently, I am seeing this issue especially, while accessing the file or particularly in this scenario viewing a diff of my commit. I could not find much on the official forum
Nothing happens when I click reload, I have to frequently restart IDE to recover from this issue!

